# Read property file in path with VM option

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I am able to read properties file with environment (LOCAL or DEV or QA) in file path of @PropertySource.

`e.g., @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:resources/env/LOCAL/mysource.properties"})`

How to read properties file with environment as VM Option (#{systemProperties['my.env.scenario']}) in @PropertySource?

**my.env.scenario can be VM option with values such as LOCAL OR DEV OR QA?**

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:resources/env/#{systemProperties['my.env.scenario']}/mysource.properties"})

@Configuration 

public class MyConfiguration {
```

}

Comment: Let's format your question, embed source code carefully.

Comment: Got my answer.                                     
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has option to set active profile.
//Enable a "DEV" profile
context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("DEV");